# How to sort the yaxis in descending order if tickpositions in highcharts are used?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, highcharts

Below is a piece of code that I have, which gives me an output like in the image.
I want the yaxis values to be sorted in the reverse order ie, the top of the Y axis should start from 9 and then 3,0. I tried `reversed:true`. But it doesn't seems to be working when tickPositions are used. But I need to use them as I have to show the bar at specific points. Is there any way to show the yaxis values in descending order along with tickPositions? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    //marginLeft: 150
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    max: 25,
    min: 0,
    reversed:true,
    tickPositions : [9,3,0]
    //tickLength: 1
  },
  yAxis: {
   // min: 0,
   // max: 10,
    title: {
      text: 'Votes',
      align: 'high'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Votes',
    data: [
      [0, 10],
      [3, 10],
      [9, 10],

    ],
    dataLabels: {
      //enabled: true,
      color: '#333',
      //inside: true
    }
  }]
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you just want it to show as normal with 0 at the coordiante root? No `reversed` needed?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    //marginLeft: 150
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    max: 25,
    //min: 0,
    reversed:false,
    tickPositions : [9,3,0]
    //tickLength: 1
  },
  yAxis: {
  reversed: false,
   min: 0,
   max: 10,
    title: {
      text: 'Votes',
      align: 'high'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Votes',
    data: [
      [0, 10],
      [3, 10],
      [9, 10],

    ],
    dataLabels: {
      //enabled: true,
      color: '#333',
      //inside: true
    }
  }]
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Meanwhile I'm faced with another puzzle. Can you please help me in resolving it?
Please find the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303779/how-to-show-tickpositions-as-start-and-end-for-each-bar-in-highcharts

Comment: @harry Great. I am glad I could help. I take a look but to be honest this was the first time I dabbled with highcharts.