# How to show tickPositions as start and end for each bar in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a bar chart with multiple bars. Each bar is representing a range with a start range and an end range. Please see the attached image.

[image]

What I'm looking for is to align the tickPositions(17 and 5) at the point where each bar meets the yaxis marked in red in the image. By specifying pointPlacement I was able to manually do so. But when the chart is generated on the fly with dynamic values it doesn't seem to work good.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Please see the code below

```html
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    //marginLeft: 150
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    max: 25,
    min: 0,
    reversed:false,
    tickPositions : [5,17]
    //tickLength: 1
  },
  yAxis: {
   // min: 0,
   // max: 10,
    title: {
      text: 'Votes',
      align: 'high'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
            series: {
             
              borderColor: '#303030',
              color : '#cac9c9'
            },
            
          },
  series: [{
    name: 'Votes',
    data: [
      [5, 0],
      [17, 10],
      

    ],
    dataLabels: {
      //enabled: true,
      color: '#333',
      //inside: true
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: Hi @harry, Could you describe the problem more precisely? How do you define the ranges? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w0vtb76L/ the columns are very narrow, so the ticks would overlap.

Comment: @ppotaczek A bar touches the yaxis at 2 points. Basically I just want to know whether it is possible to show tickPositions at those points(marked as red in the attachedimage)

Comment: Hi @harry, You would have to check the column position after chart creation and set tick positions dynamically. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fdtaow47/

Comment: @ppotaczek Really great!!! It did the trick. Please post it as an answer so that it would be helpful for someone else looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the column position after chart creation, convert pixels to axis value and set tick positions dynamically:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var point = this.series[0].points[0],
      xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
      x1 = xAxis.toValue(point.shapeArgs.x + this.plotTop),
      x2 = xAxis.toValue(
        point.shapeArgs.x + point.shapeArgs.width + this.plotTop
      );

    xAxis.update({
      tickPositions: [x1, x2]
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fdtaow47/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toValue

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load